# Cartesian to Polar Coordinates

Tags: definite-integrals

If I want to change the following integral from Cartesians to Polars:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2\,\,dx\,dy$$

in a way such that we are centered at $(a,b)$, so $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$,

Is the polar form simply $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty r^3 \,\,dr\,d\theta$$?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: There's a small typo in the equation of the circle: it should be $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 = r^2$. Nevertheless you got that right in the integral.

Comment: @DidierPiau: Thanks!

Comment: @Srivatsan: Thanks! I have edited it now. :)

Comment: Can this kind of "Is ... correct/true?" question be improved further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question:

Yes.